# How do I add a JavaScript library to my C# MVC project?

Tags: c#, google-maps, visual-studio-2013, javascript

I'm not sure how to add [this](https://github.com/ChadKillingsworth/geolocation-marker) Google maps Geolocation marker library to my project. I am using Visual Studio 2013 - how should I add it so I can then use the geolocation objects?

I have tried Googling and looking on this site but couldn't find anything useful - can anybody help?

Comment: Since it is a JavaScript library, have you tried putting the JavaScript files into your "Scripts" folder of your project (assuming a web project)? Then, just reference that file properly in your code (script tags, bundles, etc.) and use it as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

- Grab the minified version of the library in the `dist` folder, add the file to your project and link it in your pages.
- Grab the uncompiled version in the `src` folder, add to your project, and link it in your pages
- Use `bower` (http://bower.io/, you'll have to set it up if you've never used it before). You can then just do a `bower install bower-geolocationmarker` to grab the files, which you can then link to in your pages